# Why a instance of TypeError has undefined e.fileName on node?

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I'm throw a TypeError object, but in catch statement the error object has undefined lineNumber and fileName properties. I test the following code from MDN on nodejs v16:

````
try {
  throw new TypeError('Hello', "someFile.js", 10)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e instanceof TypeError)  // true
  console.log(e.message)               // "Hello"
  console.log(e.name)                  // "TypeError"
  console.log(e.fileName)              // "someFile.js"
  console.log(e.lineNumber)            // 10
  console.log(e.columnNumber)          // 0
  console.log(e.stack)                 // "@Scratchpad/2:2:9\n"
}``` 

but fileName and lineNumber still undefined.
````